# Error executing curl from php

Tags: php, linux, curl

The following code runs perfectly using POSTMAN. While I try to use the code generated by postman for PHP, it gives me errors.

**Original Code:**

```
curl -X POST \
  'http://111.93.2.38:8080/gsp/gsp/authenticate?grant_type=token' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'gspappid: 64AB7894D61644F3B5CA18B4738C700D' \
  -H 'gspappsecret: 70988876GEEEEG4504GB400G92B801E23686' \
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_PORT => "8080",
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://111.93.2.38:8080/gsp/gsp/authenticate?grant_type=token",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "gspappid: 64AB7894D61644F3B5CA18B4738C700D",
    "gspappsecret: 70988876GEEEEG4504GB400G92B801E23686",
    "postman-token: ff8278bb-b888-9fd3-6a55-780dafd58aa5"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: What do the errors look like?

Comment: Maybe you don't have cURL installed and enabled https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/curl-is-not-installed-in-your-php-installation

Answer (score 0):

What kind of error are you facing , can you please share so we can help you? 
If there is timeout error , you can try changing value of CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30